# Nuxt TypeError firebase default.a.storage is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Nuxt with Firebase and Vue. However, I'm not getting past this error:

> Nuxt.js Error:
>
> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_firebase___default.a.storage is not a function
>       at Object.61 (assets/firebase-config.js:15:28)
>       at __webpack_require** (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap f85942abf3210b58a241:25:0)
>       at Object.63 (0.server-bundle.js:70:85)
>       at **webpack_require** (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap f85942abf3210b58a241:25:0)
>       at Object.60 (pages/index.vue:7:0)
>       at **webpack_require** (webpack:/webpack/bootstrap f85942abf3210b58a241:25:0)
>       at

EDIT: Also get this error when refreshing now:

> Nuxt.js Error:
>
> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__assets_firebase_config_js**.b.auth is not a function
>       at VueComponent.isAuthenticated (2.server-bundle.js:1277:82)

The setup is straight out of the vue-cli with two pages in the `pages` directory and `firebase-config.js` in `assets`:

```
-assets
    |- firebase-config.js
-pages
    |- index.vue
    |- businesses.vue
```

Here is the contents of `firebase-config.js`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: '...',
    authDomain: '...',
    databaseURL: '...',
    storageBucket: '...',
    messagingSenderId: '...'
  })
}

const db = firebase.database()
const sphinx = firebase.auth()
const storehouse = firebase.storage()

export { db, sphinx, storehouse }
```

And how this ties into `businesses.vue`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFire from 'vuefire'
import { db, sphinx, storehouse } from '~assets/firebase-config.js'
import _ from 'lodash'

Vue.use(VueFire)
```

Any insight into why this is occurring?